# Renaming Playlist from MediaStore

Tags: android, rename, playlist, mediastore

I am trying to figure out how I can rename my playlist from the MediaStore.

Below I have the code to delete a specific playlist by passing it the specified playlist ID.

With content resolver there is a method called `resolver.delete` which makes it easy, but I don't seem to understand how I can rename specified playlist.

What would I have to do to the following code to make it rename the specified playlist.

```
    private void deletePlaylist(String playlistid) {
    // // Log.i(TAG, "deletePlaylist");

    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    String where = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID + "=?";
    String[] whereVal = { playlistid };
    resolver.delete(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, where,
            whereVal);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you still working on this? Did you try the update method, that is "update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] selectionArgs)"

Comment: I have not tried that method yet, would you be able to give me an example of how to use it based of the code I have above? thank you.

Comment: Do you have any issues with resolver.delete? I do, it deletes the m3u file but the file is recovered when I restart the Android device. I know it involves the Media Service. I wish I could delete permanently!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **update** method of ContentResolver should work. For your convenience, Google webpage at [ContentResolver update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Anyway, here's my suggested code.
I have not tried this yet, but I will:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, "NewPlaylist");

resolver.update(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
   values, "_id=" + playlistid, null);
```

Note the NewPlaylist is your updated list name, and playlistid is your existing ID. You may however have to delete the existing playlist still. I see bugs in existing Android apps (in the market) on this issue, annoying.
I like to know your progress. Keep me posted.

Comment: Thank you this works just fine. I haven't found any problem with this yet, if I do I will update you. Thank you anyway sir, have a nice rest of your day wherever you are! :)

Comment: Hey that's great. I want to make my own Playlist app since I am tired of using other apps that don't work well, bugs. I'll consider you my Playlist buddy, haha.

Comment: Feel free to contact me. I have released New Playlist Manager on Google and Amazon. (note Google have currently blocked my latest release due to so called copyright issues but the latest version is available on Amazon.

Comment: @Theo, Were you using copyrighted images in the screen shots or on any of the icons you used within the app? that can be a huge problem

Answer (score 0):

For good measure, much the same as "The Original Android". I have not found any issues with this.

```
private final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
public void renamePlaylist(Context context, String newplaylist, long playlist_id) {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String where = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID + " =? ";
    String[] whereVal = { Long.toString(playlist_id) };
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, newplaylist);
    resolver.update(uri, values, where, whereVal);
}
```